# Why does print function print everything in a reverse sequence?

Tags: geometry

I was trying to solve a Wolfram Challenge (Competitive Programming) I think. I wrote a function to find angles of a 3D triangle.

**Wolfram Mathematica**

```
angleTriangle[x1_, x2_, x3_, y1_, y2_, y3_, z1_, z2_, z3_] := 
 Module[{num, den, angle}, 
  num = (x2 - x1) (x3 - x1) + (y2 - y1) (y3 - y1) + (z2 - z1) (z3 - 
       z1);
  den = Sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 + (z2 - z1)^2]*
    Sqrt[(x3 - x1)^2 + (y3 - y1)^2 + (z3 - z1)^2];
  angle = N[ArcCos[num/den]*180/Pi];
  Round[angle, 3]]

x1 = -1;
y1 = 3;
z1 = 2;
x2 = 2;
y2 = 3;
z2 = 5;
x3 = 3;
y3 = 5;
z3 = -2;
angleA = angleTriangle[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3];
angleB = angleTriangle[x2, x3, x1, y2, y3, y1, z2, z3, z1];
angleC = angleTriangle[x3, x2, x1, y3, y2, y1, z3, z2, z1];

Print["Angles are :"];
Print["angle A = ", angleA, " degree"];
Print["angle B = ", angleB, " degree"];
Print["angle C = ", angleC, " degree"];
```

**Output**

```
angle C = 36 degree
angle B = 54 degree
angle A = 90 degree
Angles are :
```

I am confused, why the print statement writing all the answer in a reverse sequence. I can't figure out what's being written wrong in my function. If anyone can point to the right direction or assist, will be really thankful!

**Wolfram Challenge Link:** https://challenges.wolframcloud.com/challenge/angles-of-a-3d-triangle

**EDITED**
Windows 11
Mathematica 13.2.0.0
Northern Hemisphere

Comment: Are you in the southern hemisphere?  It works for me in the northern hemisphere using Windows 10 Mathematica 13.2.0.0.

Comment: In which version of Mathematica are you evaluting this? Can you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: What are the values of `$Output`  and `$Urgent`?

Comment: @JimB I am in Northern Hemisphere right now and using Windows 11. Mathematica Version 13.2.0.0

Comment: @Domen Mathematica 13.2.0.0

Comment: @Syed What you mean by ```$Output``` and ```Urgent```? And how can I see them?

Comment: Just type these in your notebook and evaluate. Use `$Echo` instead of `Print` with correct syntax to see if it changes anything.

Comment: @Syed Thanks ```Echo``` method solved it. But, can you explain, what's the difference between ```print``` & ```echo```?

Comment: I had a hunch that some output stream was blocked and that the `Print` was storing its output to some sort of LIFO buffer. That is the only way it can print in reverse. Cannot find any such thing though in the documentation so I asked you about the `$Output` etc. If this happens repeatedly and you can create a minimal example, then you should inform Tech Support. `$Echo` prints and returns the expression, so I am wildly guessing that it has to flush any temp storage. Ignore what you read.

Comment: Old Line Printer, style last line first upwards, you can read the output  as it prints, result bottom line first, mostly =43

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. You could try resetting your Mathematica installation to defaults. If you get same results, reinstall Mathematica. If that also gets same results, contact Tech Support.